# Using Scala class defined in package object from Java

Tags: scala, object, interop, package

The following Scala example defines a class inside a package object:

```
package com.mycompany

package object test {
  class MyTest {
    def foo(): Int = {
      42
    }
  }
}
```

The following three classes are generated:

```
com/mycompany/test/package.class
com/mycompany/test/package$.class
com/mycompany/test/package$MyTest.class
```

The problem arises when trying to use the `MyTest` class from Java. I think that since `package$MyTest` contains a $ in the name, Java is not acknowledging its existence. Nevertheless, the `package$` class is accessible.

Running `javap` on `package$MyTest.class` returns:

```
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public class com.mycompany.test.package$MyTest {
  public int foo();
  public com.mycompany.test.package$MyTest();
}
```

I've tried accessing the class using Eclipse, Intellij and Netbeans, without success.
Is it possible to use Scala classes defined in package objects from Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a class inside the **package object** `test` is currently not implemented the same way as defining it inside the **package** `test`, although it probably should (this is being tracked as [SI-4344](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4344)).

Because of that, it is usually good practice to place into the package object only definitions that cannot be top level, like vals, defs, etc. (this is the whole point of package objects after all), and leave class/object definitions into a normal package definition:

```
package com.mycompany

package object test {
  // vals, defs, vars, etc.
  val foobar = 42
}

package test {
  // classes, objects, traits, etc.
  class MyTest {
    def foo(): Int = {
      42
    }
  }
}
```

This will produce a normal `MyTest` class, easily accessible from Java:

```
com/mycompany/test/MyTest.class
com/mycompany/test/package.class
com/mycompany/test/package$.class
```

Comment: This is useful when I am writing the package class, but not when I am using a third party library.

Answer (score 3):

`package$MyTest` follows JVM convention for nested classes, so it would be visible as `package.MyTest`... except this isn't a legal name in Java. Which means it can't be accessed.

Comment: So .. *then* what ..  I have `type`s in the package object that are used ubiquitously in the classes in the package. Then .. for all of the (hundred or so) classes / traits etc we need to do an `import SomeContainer._`  where `SomeContainer` is a java-friendly alternative to the package object?

Comment: You can't use `type`s in Java anyway.

Comment: I discovered that little "treat" (no `type`s in java ..)  soon after seeing this answer.  It seems that using scala framework within java is basically a non-starter ;(  .   I am creating a separate adapter to allow a subset of the scala functionality to be accessible through java.  This places a firm limitation on the ability to use scala : it  can not be considered general purpose within java / scala teams : only java -> scala really works beyond simple things.

Comment: Using a Scala framework which isn't intended for it can be, yes. Note that you can use full power of Scala for the implementation, the limitation is only on the API. But you'll run into the same problem for any similar pair of languages, e.g. C and C++.

Comment: Not able to use `type`s or `trait`'s .. that's almost no longer `scala` ..  We are keeping scala separate from java handling since too many core scala features are incompatible.