# How implement scala trait from package object as java interface?

Tags: java, scala, maven, traits

I have a java maven project which has dependency to scala project. I try to implement scala trait in java. The trait is store in packge object, when I try to implement it project fallen with compile time error Here sources:

scala source:

```
package com.compile.error

package object dummies {
    trait BaseDummy {
        def name: String
    }
    trait ChildDummy extends BaseDummy{

    }
}
```

java source:

```
//Uncoment for compile error
public class WhantImplementScalaTrait  /*implements com.compile.error.dummies.package$ChildDummy*/ {
}
```

So how implement scala trait as java interface if it in package object?

Full sources you can download [here](https://github.com/C-h-e-r-r-y/ScalaTriatCompiletimeJavaError).

**UPDATED**

The command

```
javap package$ChildDummy.class
```

Gets result:

```
public interface com.compile.error.dummies.package$ChildDummy extends com.compile.error.dummies.package$BaseDummy {
}
```

**Tried imports**

- com.compile.error.dummies.package$.ChildDummy$Class
- com.compile.error.dummies.package$.ChildDummy
- com.compile.error.dummies.package$.MODULE$.ChildDummy$Class
- com.compile.error.dummies.package$.MODULE$.ChildDummy
- com.compile.error.dummies.package$ChildDummy
- com.compile.error.dummies.package$ChildDummy$Class

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436074/scala-trait-companion-object-is-not-visible-in-java) but it about *methods* **not** about interfaces.

Comment: You could try using reflection list all the classes in that package, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Scala class defined in package object from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170058/using-scala-class-defined-in-package-object-from-java)