# How can I call a case class defined on a Scala package object from Java?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I can not access the case class that is in the package object.

I have a Scala code:

```
package com.github.somepkg

package object reactiveconfig {

  /**
    * Pre-parsed data,
    */
  type Parsed

  /**
    * Value stored in internal key->value Map
    */
  case class Value[ParsedData](parsedData: ParsedData, version: Long)

  /**
    * Represents successfully parsed KeyValue
    */
  case class ParsedKeyValue[ParsedData](key: String, value: Value[ParsedData])

  //...
}
```

Now I need to call this in Java:

```
com.github.somepkg.reactiveconfig.package$.MODULE$
```

But no access to the case class:

```
com.github.somepkg.reactiveconfig.package$.MODULE$.Value(parsedData, 22) //Error, no access to the case class
```

Comment: You should not define classes in a package object. The best would be to move them outside the package object, but leave them in the same package. That way you can reference them using the fully-qualified name without problems.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This is an existing library. I can not change anything in this library.

Comment: `com.github.somepkg.reactiveconfig.package$.MODULE$.Value.apply(parsedData, 22)`

Comment: @cchantep This does not work. Error: "cannot find symbol variable Value"

Comment: use reflect `Class.forName("com.github.somepkg.reactiveconfig.package$Value").getConstructors()[0].newInstance(1,1)`

Comment: @George AlexeyRomanov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23171257/5249621): "`package$MyTest` follows JVM convention for nested classes, so it would be visible as `package.MyTest`... except this isn't a legal name in Java. Which means it can't be accessed." So try to use 余杰水's comment with reflection.